# Sectioned listview with Search option

Tags: android, android-listview, android-search

I want to create a custom Sectioned ListView in which the Search option can be used. I have searched for various codes, But couldn't find anything appropriate and correct for my case. Any suggestions on how to go about this issue. Thanks in Advance.